# Monitor Kafka Log offset using JMX for old consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to monitor the consumer lag for old consumer groups ( which uses zookeeper) using JMX.

This is how I have enabled JMX.

```
export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=`hostname -f` -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
if [ "x$ISKAFKASERVER" == "xtrue" ]; then
export JMX_PORT=9887
```

And I am able to see multiple been when I connect using `JConsole`. However I don't see **kafka.consumer**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you enabled jmx on kafka brokers. You need to enable jmx on the instances where consumer is running for getting consumer metrics

Comment: would you please elborate, I have standalone instance not a cluster, and both broker and consumers are running on the same node.

Comment: You need to enable jmx on app which is running consumer/producer to get the consumer/producer metrics . Enabling jmx on broker won't fetch you consumer/producer metrics.Running broker and consumer on same node is fine but they would be separate instances , so you need to enable jmx on instance which is running consumer

Comment: and how do I do that, I tried to put those things in my `consumer.propery` file however it's not working

Comment: if your consumer is running via java app then it should passed as jvm argument or if you are using kaka-console-consumer script then add it in the startup script like "export JMX_PORT=<any_port>"

Comment: I am using the confluent connector, which actually creates the consumers.